# SQL Query to copy field and split in to 2

Tags: sql, date, time, view

hi I'm new to sql im  trying to copy a field in SQL table to then split the date and time out

Column name :- DocumentDate

date I want to split:- 2020-02-12 00:00:00.000 into a new field called DATE , TIME

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. (And a timestamp has a year _field_, a month _field_ etc.)

Comment: sorry i want to copy a column in to a new one with only the date stamp

Comment: The Answer might depend on what Database Management System DBMS you are using. Please add a Tag to tell the readers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DBMS. If that does not work in your case, edit your question to contain the DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, Vertica, Teradata ...) as a tag.

Many databases allow you to cast a timestamp to a date, and to subtract the timestamp cast as date from the timestamp, and cast the result as time.

```
WITH
indata(ts) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-02-12 00:00:00.000'
)
SELECT
  CAST(ts AS DATE) AS dt
, CAST(ts - CAST(ts AS DATE) AS TIME) AS tm
FROM indata;
-- out      dt     |    tm    
-- out ------------+----------
-- out  2020-02-12 | 00:00:00
```

Comment: Alternatively `CAST(ts AS TIME) AS tm`.